# setting display results from json by id value returned

Tags: php

I have pulled my json results and using the following. but i need them to display to order by position 1.2.3 right now its 4321

```
 foreach($result['channels'] as $item){    

    $name = $item['name'];
    $position = $item['position'];
    $channel_id =  $item['id'];

    echo '<div class="channel">
            <div class="channel-name">'.$name.'</div>
          </div>';

}
```

Comment: did you try sorting the array?

Comment: i tried sorting it did nothing I tried multi sort array again nothing

Comment: It would help if you show what you tried instead of just having someone do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`usort()`](https://php.net/usort) before to use the `foreach()` :

```
usort($result['channels'], function($a, $b) {
    return $a['position'] - $b['position'];
});

foreach($result['channels'] as $item){    

    $name = $item['name'];
    $position = $item['position'];
    $channel_id =  $item['id'];

    echo '<div class="channel">
            <div class="channel-name">'.$name.'</div>
          </div>';

}
```

Comment: thanks @Syscall it worked  I had tried this  here http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php but wasnt working for me.

Comment: @Codi You're welcome :) `sort()` doesn't works to sort using a custom field. `usort()` will helps you to solve many of sort issues in the future ;)